# Notification when visitor is on specific WordPress Article

Tags: posts

I am desperately attempting to find a way to get an alert when a specific article on my WordPress is visited (and no, I will not be flooded by emails, the code will be used temporarely) Being new to php, I used this code, but the site gets a critical error if I put it into the functions.php?

```
 function email_alert() {
        wp_mail( 'aprilia@example.net', 'Alert', 'This Site was Visited!' );
    }

  if(is_article(1234)){
    }
    add_action( 'wp', 'email_alert' );
```

please help/advice, a big thank you!

Comment: In general when you get a critical error from WordPress there will be more details in the email it sends you or in the server error log.

Comment: `is_article()` isn't a function.  WordPress has no idea what to with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [article](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138473/if-is-pagepage-id-not-working/251528), I think a specific post could be adressed like this

```
function email_alert() {
global $post;

if( $post->ID == 1234) { 

        wp_mail( 'aprilia@example.net', 'Alert', 'This Site was Visited!' );
    }

add_action( 'wp', 'email_alert' );

}
```

however, emails are still not being sent for some reasons. happy for all inputs and help

Comment: The add_action needs to be outside the email_alert function's closing brace.

Comment: Do you know that wp_mail works? Does your site send emails at all?

Comment: @Rup you made my day! it is working now, thank you very much for being so patient!

Answer (score 1):

There's no `is_article`. I assume you guessed there would be analogously to is_page, but I don't think article is a built-in WordPress post type. I think you want is_page instead, which looks like it covers all post types.

You should also move the page check into the action handler, to be sure that WordPress has enough state loaded to know if it's on that page or not at the point it does the check, which it won't when it's loading the plugin or theme you've added this code to, e.g.

```php
function email_alert() {
    if ( is_page( 1234 ) ) {
        wp_mail( 'aprilia@example.net', 'Alert', 'This Site was Visited!' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'email_alert' );
```

Comment: thank you - site is no more stalling :-) but email is not being sent...

Answer (score 1):

here we go, this is the code that works, triggering an email-alert when a specific article is viewed

```
function email_alert() {
global $post;

if( $post->ID == 1234) { 

        wp_mail( 'aprilia@example.net', 'Alert', 'This Site was Visited!' );
    }
} 

add_action( 'wp', 'email_alert' );
```