# Trigger email alert if file downloaded

Tags: functions

I've found [this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383824/notification-when-visitor-is-on-specific-wordpress-article) which triggers an email alert when an article is viewed, but wondered if a similar technique is possible for when a specific file is downloaded?

```
function article_email_alert() {
global $post;
if( $post->ID == 1234) { 
        wp_mail( 'sam@example.net', 'Alert', 'The article was visited.' );
    }
} 
add_action( 'wp', 'article_email_alert' );
```

Comment: That would be trickier, since most of the time a download means someone clicks a link directly to the file. When a file is downloaded, none of WP's functionality is loaded. How are visitors to your site downloading files? If they're embedded on the site, say a PDF that's embedded on the page, then you could probably find a way. It might be easier to look into something like Google Analytics Events to track when files are downloaded, and have GA periodically send email summaries of that report.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine, I thought that might be the case. This is for a downloadable/viewable in browser PDF file. I think your solution for Google Analytics sounds good, I'll give it a whirl.