# Side bar only if it's not a single post or a specific page

Tags: php, sidebar, conditional-tags

I'm trying to make my sidebar appear only if it's 'not a post' or if it's 'not a specific page'.

This is what I've tried.

```
<?php if (!is_single() || !is_page('about') ) { get_sidebar() } ;?>

<?php if (!is_single() or !is_page('about') ) { get_sidebar() } ;?>
```

It's not working. I was able to suppress the sidebar on a single post, but when I add the 'or about page' it doesn't work. I'm thinking it's my syntax or logic.  I am not well-versed in PHP.

Comment: Where are you trying to call this?  Is it in a function or an actual template file?

Comment: In addition to @rudtek's comment, check to make sure the slug is correct for your about page. You can also try `global $post; if ( $post->ID == 123 ) { get_sidebar() }` (the `123` being the id of your about page) as per [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138473/if-is-pagepage-id-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

I might not be fully awake, but it seems to me the operator should be "and", not "or":

```php
if ( ! is_single() && ! is_page( 'about' ) ) {
    get_sidebar();
}
```

The `is_single()` checks if the main query is for a single post, and `is_page()` checks if the main query is for a specified page.

Because you don't want the sidebar to show on single posts, exclude that by `! is_single()`, which leaves you with all other content types except posts. From there, we also want to prevent display on the `about` page, so add `! is_page( 'about' )` to allow other pages but not the `about` page.

Comment: This conditional would only hold true if it's neither of the 2, so if it was one or the other it would still show.

Comment: I think that's incorrect. Here's the `if` statement in sentence form: "If it's not a singular post and it's not the `about` page, then display the sidebar." And actually if one is true then the other is also true (because they test different post types).

Comment: @caleb Makes a lot of sense. Thank you.  And you did it half asleep!

I'm going to give it a try.